# angularjs loses binding between dom and scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a directive very similar to ng-repeat , with some differences.
I am creating multiple documentFragments and appending the transcludeFn(clone) output to one of the many documentFragments. at the end of the iterations I append these documentFragments to the parent element.

Now, I am not looking for an alternative to this directive. I am very well aware that i can use multiple ng-repeat in my directive template without the need to create dom elemnts myself.

the elements gets rendered with their respective scope. everything looks fine at the end but
problem is ,when I add the clone elements (transclude function output) to documentFragments and consequently add them to dom tree, angular somehow miss the link between dom elements and their scope.

angular.element(createdDomElement).scope() returns the parent scope rather than the createdDom own scope.

**Update:**
I found for some reason ,ng-scope class on created dom elements disappear after rendering the view!

```
.directive('itemGrid', ['$window', function ($window) {
     return {
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 1000,
        terminal: true,
        compile: function compile($elem, $attrs, linker) {
           return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
              var attrData = attrs.itemGrid,
                 match = attrData.match(/^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.*?)\s*(\s+track\s+by\s+(.+)\s*)?$/),
                 indexString = match[1],
                 collection = scope.$eval(match[2]);

             drawGrid = function (numberOfColumns) {
                 columns = Array.apply(null, new Array(numberOfColumns)).map(function () {
                    return  document.createDocumentFragment(); // row fragments
                 });

                 var cloneIt = function (clone) {
                    columns[columnIndex].insertBefore(clone[0], null);
                 };
                 for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
                ------   calculate columnIndex------
                   var newScope = scope.$new();
                    newScope[indexString] =collection[i];
                    linker(newScope, cloneIt);
                 }
                 columnsFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
                 for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                    column = document.createElement('ul');
                    column.className = columnClasses;
                    column.appendChild(columns[i]);
                    columnsFragment.appendChild(column);
                 }
                 elem.parent()[0].appendChild(columnsFragment);
              };
            }
```

Comment: Can you show some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: added the relevant part of the directive I'm working on.